# Dplyr mutate divide two columns with NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Below is an example dataframe:

```
a = c("x","y","z")
b = c(1,2,NA)
c = c(4,NA,6)
c_b = c(4,NA,6)
df=data.frame(a,b,c,c_b)
```

I want to mutate as:

```
dplyr::mutate(c_b = c/b)
```

The issue is I want to keep the `NA` values when `c` (numerator) is `NA`, but keep the value of `c` when `b` is `NA`!

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(c_b = coalesce(c/b, c))
```

-output

```
   a  b  c c_b
1 x  1  4   4
2 y  2 NA  NA
3 z NA  6   6
```